# Using php with html with in Aptana

Tags: php, html, aptana

This is my first time using php. I am having a little trouble starting out simple such as just printing "hello world" through php inside an html document. I have an html document with various elements in it and when I print

```
  <?php echo "hello world" ?>
```

The html document won't accept the php tags. I have read that html docs won't accept php tags, if this is true how do I integrate php and html? If I just use a php file aptana won't allow me to preview the document.

Comment: `.html` files can run as PHP, you just need to tell the server to treat them as such.

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension from HTML to PHP. View it in the browser instead of inside Aptana. Also add a semi-colon to the end of the string.

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

It sounds like you need to read a really basic tutorial on setting up a webserver locally by the way.

XAMPP is pretty popular so take a look at this guide: https://www.udemy.com/blog/xampp-tutorial/

Comment: sounds about right. the biggest thing being the `.html` to `.php`

Comment: The semi-colon isn't required for a one-liner as such, although it is good practice to do so (and just as long as it's the last line). Plus, the `?>` is also something that doesn't need to be there, unless HTML is placed underneath PHP. Another thing is that `.html` can be treated to run as PHP.

Comment: While they're on hello world I don't think they need to know how to run .html as PHP :P

Comment: Thanks, I actually am using XAMPP. Is the preview function in aptana just broken? So I guess when ever I have a page that includes any type of php I just should save as php (which I'm guessing will also accept html tags).

Comment: The preview function you see in a lot of IDEs is for plain old HTML. PHP needs to be processed so you can only view it in a browser. This isn't a bug in your IDE.